# why I cant install fluent_ui?

Tags: flutter, fluent-ui

i get this error

Because fluent_ui >=3.10.0 depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0, fluent_ui >=3.10.0 requires intl 0.18.0.
So, because window_project depends on fluent_ui ^4.3.0 which depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.

I have upgraded and installed again.
but it doesnt work

Comment: I can't find a better answer than the error it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to downgrade your `fluent_ui` <= 3.10.0. The error kinda clear: `fluent_ui` >= 3.10.0 requires `intl` 0.18.0, so u just need to downgrade your  `fluent_ui` version.